# Consider the random continous variable $Y \sim D(y; \vec{\theta})$: what can be inferred about $g(Y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Y$ be an iid continuous and random variable such that $Y \sim f(y;\vec{
\theta})$ with $\theta$ a series of parameters $\theta_1, ..., \theta_k$ and $D$ a probability distribution. We know that, provided that these integrals exist,

$$\mathbb{E} (Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty yf(y;\vec{\theta}) \space dy$$

and

$$\mathbb{E} (g(Y)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(y)f(y;\vec{\theta}) \space dy$$

where $g(Y)$ is a function of $Y$.

Does this imply $g(Y) \sim D(y; \vec{\theta})$ as well? And besides from $\mathbb{E}(g(Y)), \mathbb{V}(g(Y))$, what else can be inferred about $g(Y)$ from the distribution of $Y$? I'm particularly curious about whether the properties of $g$ itself may determine something about the statistical properties of $g(Y)$.

#### Context and narrowing down

I'm studying the properties of a Gamma-distributed variable $Y$ with $\alpha=0.93, \beta=217$ and its related variable $Y^{-1}$. To be clear, $Y^{-1}$ is a random variable containing the reciprocals of $Y$.

I'm also interested in two ways of computing the proportion of *each element* of a random variable $X$ with respect to *all elements* in $Y$, where $X$ also follows a gamma distribution although with different parameters.

A straightforward way to compute this is to take

$$f(X)=X/\mu_Y$$

This is, the proportion of each $x \in X$ with respect to the average of $Y$.

A second plausible way is computing the average proportion each $x$ has with respect to all $Y$. This is, for each $x_i$, consider $p_i = \text{mean}(x_i * Y^{-1})$. Then we have a variable $P = p_1, p_2, ...$ containing the average proportion each $x_i$ has with respect to every $Y$.

I'm simply trying to refine my understanding of the variables involved in this operations. As you can see, functions of $Y$ and $X$ appear repeatidely, and I wanted to know how much information I can extract from knowing their respective distributions.

Comment: One example to think about is if $Y$ is normal then $Y^2$ is chi-squared. What sort of statistical properties are you asking about? Moments? Quantiles? Can you narrow your question down?

Comment: I added context in an edit. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution#Derivation_from_Gamma_distribution

Comment: That is *exactly* the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you @Henry. Any other resource on this distribution is appreciated.